# Applying coldfusion 8 Update 1

Tags: coldfusion

I'm running ColdFusion 8 Enterprise Edition on RHEL 4 32bit. I tried applying the ColdFusion 8 Update 1 (8.0.1) but the installation fails with the error below. Can anyone help?

Thank you.

===============================================================================

### Installing...

===============================================================================

### Installation Aborted

The installation of the Adobe ColdFusion 8.0.1 did not complete successfully.

Please make sure that the ColdFusion MX server has been shut down prior to
running the installer again.

All services related to coldfusion, webserver, jrun are stopped alerady.

Comment: [sf] might be a better place to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about Red Hat but if you get this error on Windows then you need to stop all the JRun services to complete the update.

This article here has a section on starting a CF service on Linux http://www.aaronwest.net/blog/index.cfm/2011/2/7/Super-Guide-Installing-ColdFusion-9-on-CentOS-Linux I am pretty sure if you substitute start for stop in that command you might have some joy.